# Wikitude Error - "Unable to find ARchitect World path in App resouce bundle"

Tags: ios, xcode5, wikitude

I've got following error after I integrated Wikitude SDK into my application.

Unable to find ARchitect World path in App resouce bundle: 5_BrowsingPois_6_CaptureScreenBonus
Wikitude SDK: ARchitect Build: b2af9d1
Application name not licensed.
Application name: some name
Licensed name(s): com.wikitude.SDKExamples
2014-05-14 16:18:12.265 SpotInfo[4945:60b] <0x1767b520 WTStandardARViewController.m:(96)> ARchitect is running with version: 3.3.0

Please I need some guidance how to solve this out? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you created your project by adapting the Wikitude samples project. I suggest you to set up your project from scratch as described in the Wikitude [documentation](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/ios/setupguideios.html). That's easier than removing the code you don't need from the samples app.

Comment: Hi,ChrisE thank you for your reply. I have found a solution after I struggling days, its about how you adding web content of Wikitude into your project and that should be set according to recommended path structure. That why Wikitude displaying this error.